# How do I use a variable outside of the function it was created in

Tags: ios, swift, function

I am trying to figure out how I can use a variable outside of the function it was created in without using return. Example:

```
import UIKit
var Finalvar = "test"
func test(var1: String) {
    var Finalvar = var1

}
test(var1: "Done")
print(Finalvar)
```

as output I get "test" instead of "done", how can I change that?

Comment: remove the var inside function. You are redeclaring the variable

Comment: Don't create a new variable inside the function, just do `Finalvar = var1`. However, most importantly, read the Swift book as a start, you seem to lack key concepts such as scopes of variables. Also variable and function names should be lower-camelCase (`finalvar`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `Finalvar` is not `Finalvar`

The **global variable** `Finalvar` and the **local variable** `Finalvar` are two different objects.

If you declare a local variable with the same name as a global variable the global variable is hidden.

Remove the `var` keyword in the function

```
var finalVar = "test"

func test(var1: String) {
    finalVar = var1

}
test(var1: "Done")
print(finalVar)
```

In a class or struct you can use `self`  to indicate to access the property.

```
self.finalVar = var1
```

Note : Variable (and function) names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: It seems to be global function so self will not work

Comment: Probably better to use a inout keyword

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring a new `Finalvar`again in your `func test()`, just leave out the declaration out in your function. The code below should work:

```
import UIKit
var finalVar = "test"
func test(var1: String) {
   finalVar = var1

}
test(var1: "Done")
print(finalVar)
```

One additional important thing -> please begin your variables with lowercase instead of a capital letter